# Bilinear Interpolation image resizing marks & 'splotches'

Tags: c, image, image-processing, bitmap, interpolation

I'm making an image resizing program in C and at the moment I'm having trouble with the Bilinear Interpolation function (it's one of many I'm using). This problem only arises for 16-bit bitmaps, If I use 24-bit versions, it resizes them perfectly.

Here's my code for the Bilinear Interpolation. n_w and n_h are the new widths and heights of the image:

```
#define getelm(x)   (((pix+index)->x)*(1-xdiff)*(1-ydiff))+(((pix+index+1)->x)*(xdiff)*(1-ydiff))+(((pix+index+o_w)->x)*(1-xdiff)*(ydiff))+((pix+index+o_w+1)->x)*xdiff*ydiff

int pad = (2*n_w) & 3;
if (pad)
pad = 4-pad;
uint16_t *buffer;
if (buf)
buffer = malloc(2*n_w);
for (i = 0; i < n_h; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n_w; j++) {
        x = (int)(j*xrat);
        y = (int)(i*yrat);
        xdiff = (xrat*j)-x;
        ydiff = (yrat*i)-y;
        index = y*o_w+x;
        uint16_t container = 0;
        container |= (int)(round(getelm(b))) << 11;
        container |= (int)(round(getelm(g))) << 5;
        container |= (int)round(getelm(r));
        if (buf)
            *(buffer+j) = container;
        else
            fwrite(&container, 1, 2, dest);
    }
    if (buf)
        fwrite(buffer, 1, 2*n_w, dest);
        fwrite(&pad, 1, pad, dest);
}
```

My 24-bit version of this code (where the only difference is that the container is not used and instead 3 8-bit integers hold the RGB values) works beautifully.

This code, however, gives weird results. Look at the image below:[image: Original image]

When I resize this, it gives me this back: [image: Resized image]

I can't see why this would be happening, especially when it works for 24-bit bitmaps, and also that some other resizing algorithms (Nearest Neighbour for example) work with 16-bit in the same way that this should.

EDIT:
I don't think it's an overflow problem, because adding the following code gives no output when run:

```
if (MAX((int)(getelm(b)), 31) > 31)
    printf("blue overflow: %.10f\n", (getelm(b)));
if (MAX((int)(getelm(g)), 63) > 63)
    printf("green overflow: %.10f\n", (getelm(g)));
if (MAX((int)(getelm(r)), 31) > 31)
    printf("red overflow: %.10f\n", (getelm(r)));
```

EDIT 2:
I don't think it's an underflow problem either, this does nothing:

```
if ((getelm(b)) < 0 || (getelm(g)) < 0 || (getelm(r)) < 0)
    printf("Underflow\n");
```

Comment: Have you tried testing the result of getelem() to make sure that it is of the proper width and not spilling over, outside its expected range? This would explain the overbright pixels, and the fact that it works in 24 bit.

Comment: And what if you test for *underflow*? A negative value will be set to max after casting to unsigned.

Comment: Ya, I just left another edit

Comment: Okay... does it work when you convert your 5-6-5 to 8-8-8 and then back? It must be something in your calculations; the bad image shows *some* sort of overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the data in `pix` have the type

```
struct
{
    uint16_t r : 5;
    uint16_t g : 6;
    uint16_t b : 5;
};
```

there's a bug in the calculation of `container`. Using `round` won't always prevent overflow. The next code will:

```
uint16_t container = 0;
        container |= ((int)(round(getelm(b))) & 31) << 11; // optionally
        container |= ((int)(round(getelm(g))) & 63) << 5;
        container |= ((int)round(getelm(r)) & 31);
```

or to retain a maximum of the lost information:

```
uint16_t container = 0;
        container |= min((int)(round(getelm(b))) , 31) << 11;
        container |= min(((int)(round(getelm(g))) , 63) << 5;
        container |= min(((int)round(getelm(r)) , 31);
```

**EDIT**

Since `pix->r`, `pix->g` and `pix->b` come from 8bit values, a same reasoning apply to them and their range needs to be checked.

Since a white region turns to purple this means that the green color is suppressed due to overflows or it's read as zero in the first place. In this case inspecting read color can help.
Similarly, a black color turns into green means a bit representing a small value is shifted and the color is somehow inverted.

To find the bug I recommend splitting the code into small functions and asserting the input of each one of them.

Comment: The data in pix doesn't come from a struct that has the bitfield size predefined, as the same struct is used for 24-bit values. It just reads the each 5, 6, and 5 bit value into the corresponding uint8_t variable. Since they're smaller than 8 bits, they'll fit, so there's no need for an extra struct. I can't get the code above to work though, there's no difference

Comment: Sorry, the observation I made doesn't help. I'll edit with more general information that could help!